# Need way to Compare Two Tables by Date, sum values in table 2 by date, & output values to a 3rd table w/ totals of table 1

Tags: sql, batch-file, ms-access, vba

I've been trying to rack my brain over this for over a week. I'm not strong in SQL syntax or Access so I started programming logic to do what I needed in batch and while it kind of works, it is very slow and clunky. I'd prefer to get this working in MS Access.

What I need is to compare the SLIPDATE of the "Sales-End-of-Day-Cashout-Slips" table/spreadsheet, (see example of table/spreadsheet below),

```
ID  SLIPDATE    Cash    Credit  SC      Off By      Total
1   21/11/2011  89.9    160.7   61.87   0.5         312.97
2   21/11/2011  43.45   49.24           7.2         99.89
4   21/11/2011  129.7   62.6    6.05    0.39        198.74
3   21/11/2011  41.83   8.57    20.16               70.56
5   21/11/2011  162.45  68.34   6.05    0.1         236.94
6   21/11/2011  313.8   348.98  48      0.34        711.12
7   21/11/2011  21.27   5       3                   29.27
8   21/11/2011  380.48  494.69  47.17   15.25       937.59
...
```

To the "Sales-Report-01-01-2011-01-31-2011" table/spreadsheet (see example of table/spreadsheet below):

```
SALEID  Date        Amount  Tax 1   Tax 2   Tax 3   Discount
1613    1/1/2011    $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00 
1613    1/1/2011    $0.50   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00 
1614    1/1/2011    $0.75   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00 
1614    1/1/2011    $0.75   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00 
1614    1/1/2011    $0.75   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00 
1614    1/1/2011    $0.50   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00 
1614    1/1/2011    $1.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   $0.00 
...
```

I need a query, macro, or script to add up all the values of the Current Date (there are multiple values for each day) and update/generate the values of the "Sales-Report-Compared" table/spreadsheet with the "Date,Slip Total,Stats,Stats Tax,Stats Discount,Stats Total,Match (Yes/No)".

```
Date,Slip Total,Stats,Stats Tax,Stats Discount,Stats Total,Match (Yes/No),
,,,,,,,
```

Somewhere along the way I started confusing myself with script logic with how advanced it became but here's the script that I was working on:

```
@echo off
@title=
REM IMPROVEMENTS
REM - Reporting sales count per day/date. If current date is the same and ID is different, add to count and exclude duplicates.
REM - Include ID, Date, Price, Discount, & Taxes
REM - Generate a grand total of the Total Net Price minus Taxes & Discount
REM - Cleanup file and remove unneeded code (such as count with new methods)
REM - Cleanup the count to only add up the totals at the end of each date loop
REM - You need to take the price out in a different loop or it breaks.

:_mainFunction
    CALL :_setDefaults
    CALL :_setVariables
    REM CALL :_generateCompareToDates
    CALL :_runAuditFunction
GOTO :EOF
EXIT


REM // ---------------------------- Functions ----------------------------- //

:_runAuditFunction
    REM Parses the file to create an output spreadsheet
    cd /d "%reportPath%"

    for /f %%a IN (H:\LEETERS-POS-Extender\POS-Sales-Reports\By-Month\Parsed\compareDates.txt) DO (
        for /f %%b IN ('dir /b') DO (
            for /f "eol=; skip=1 tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17* delims=," %%c IN (%%b) DO (              
                REM Debugging

                REM CompareDates Path=%%a CurrentFile=%%b
                REM ID1=%%c Date1=%%d Time=%%e Item Name=%%f
                REM Price=%%g Tax1-Price=%%i Tax2=%%k Tax3=%%j
                REM Discount='%%k' Count=%%l Employee=%%m

                REM Logic to add up cents to price
                REM IF Cents1 GEQ 100 SET /A Price2=Price2+1 & SET /A Cents1=Cents1-100
                REM CLS & echo '%%a' '%%b' '%%c' '%%d' '%%e' '%%f' '%%g' '%%h' '%%i' '%%j' '%%k' '%%l' '%%m' '%%n' '%%o'

                CLS
                echo Compare Path=%compareDates%
                echo Compare Date='%%a'
                echo Current File='%%b'
                echo ID1='%%c'  Date1='%%d'  Time='%%e'  
                echo Item-Name='%%f' Price=%%g
                echo Tax1-Price=%%h Tax2-Price=%%i Tax3-Price=%%j
                echo Discount-Price='%%k' 
                echo Count=%%l
                echo Employee=%%m
                echo.
                CALL :_calculatePrices %%g %%h %%i %%j %%k
                REM pause

                CALL :_CompareValues %%d %%a %%g %%h %%i %%j %%c %%k
                REM CALL :_GenerateLogFiles
            )
            CALL :_GenerateOutput %%c %currentDate% %AmountDollarPrice% %AmountChangePrice% %Tax1DollarPrice% %Tax1ChangePrice% %DiscountDollarPrice% %DiscountChangePrice%
        )
    )
    EXIT
GOTO :EOF

:_calculatePrices
    REM Create a cleaner loop
    for /f "eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10* delims=$. " %%o IN ("%1 %2 %3 %4 %5") DO (
        echo Calculating...
        echo "%currentDate%" == "%compareDate%" 
        echo Values: '%%o' '%%p' '%%q' '%%r' '%%s' %%t' '%%u' '%%v' %%w' '%%x'

        REM Adds up the Dollar Prices and Change Prices up
        IF "%currentDate%" == "%compareDate%" (
            SET /a AmountDollarPrice=%AmountDollarPrice%+%%o
            SET /a AmountChangePrice=%AmountChangePrice%+%%p

            SET /a Tax1DollarPrice=%Tax1DollarPrice%+%%q
            SET /a Tax1ChangePrice=%Tax1ChangePrice%+%%r

            SET /a Tax2DollarPrice=%Tax2DollarPrice%+%%s
            SET /a Tax2ChangePrice=%Tax2ChangePrice%+%%t

            SET /a Tax3DollarPrice=%Tax3DollarPrice%+%%u
            SET /a Tax3ChangePrice=%Tax3ChangePrice%+%%v

            SET /a DiscountDollarPrice=%DiscountDollarPrice%+%%w
            SET /a DiscountChangePrice=%DiscountChangePrice%+%%x
        )

        CALL :_calcPriceLogic

        echo AmountDollarPrice=%AmountDollarPrice% AmountChangePrice=%AmountChangePrice%
        echo Tax1DollarPrice=%Tax1DollarPrice% Tax1ChangePrice=%Tax1ChangePrice%
        echo Tax2DollarPrice=%Tax2DollarPrice% Tax2ChangePrice=%Tax2ChangePrice%
        echo Tax3DollarPrice=%Tax3DollarPrice% Tax3ChangePrice=%Tax3ChangePrice%
        echo DiscountDollarPrice=%DiscountDollarPrice% DiscountChangePrice=%DiscountChangePrice%
    )   
GOTO :EOF

:_calcPriceLogic
    REM Removes GEQ 100 from Change, adds to VariableDollarPrice, and loops until not GEQ 100
    IF %AmountChangePrice% GEQ 100 (
        SET /a AmountDollarPrice=%AmountDollarPrice%+1
        SET /a AmountChangePrice=%AmountChangePrice%-100
    )
    IF %Tax1ChangePrice% GEQ 100 (
        SET /a Tax1DollarPrice=%Tax1DollarPrice%+1
        SET /a Tax1ChangePrice=%Tax1ChangePrice%-100
    )
    IF %Tax2ChangePrice% GEQ 100 (
        SET /a Tax2DollarPrice=%Tax2DollarPrice%+1
        SET /a Tax2ChangePrice=%Tax2ChangePrice%-100
    )
    IF %Tax3ChangePrice% GEQ 100 (
        SET /a Tax3DollarPrice=%Tax3DollarPrice%+1
        SET /a Tax3ChangePrice=%Tax3ChangePrice%-100
    )
    IF %DiscountChangePrice% GEQ 100 (
        SET /a DiscountDollarPrice=%DiscountDollarPrice%+1
        SET /a DiscountChangePrice=%DiscountChangePrice%-100
    )
GOTO :EOF

:_generateCompareToDates
REM Creates the compare file with only dates
cd /d %reportPath%

IF NOT EXIST %compareDates% (
    for /f %%a IN ('dir /b') DO (
        for /f "eol=; skip=1 tokens=1,2,3* delims=, " %%b IN (%%a) DO (
            CALL :_setVar firstItem %%c
            CALL :_checkIsDuplicate %%c
            CALL :_setVar nextItem %%c
        )
    )
) ELSE (
    REM Skip Loop
)
GOTO :EOF

:_setCount
    set /a count=%count%+1
GOTO :EOF

:_setVar
    set %3 %1=%2
GOTO :EOF

:_checkIsDuplicate
    IF "%firstItem%" == "%nextItem%" (
        REM Date is duplicate, skip file
    ) ELSE (
        REM Date is not a duplicate, append file
        echo %firstItem% >> "%reportPath%/Parsed/compareDates.txt"
    )
GOTO :EOF

:_setLocal
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
GOTO :EOF

:_setVariables
    REM CALL :_setVar count 1 /a
    REM CALL :_setVar scriptPath "H:\LEETERS-POS-Extender\POS Sales Reports"
    REM CALL :_setVar reportPath "%scriptPath%\By Month\"
    REM CALL :_setVar compareDates "%reportPath%\Parsed\compareDates.txt"
    CALL :_setVar scriptPath "H:\LEETERS-POS-Extender\POS-Sales-Reports"
    CALL :_setVar reportPath "H:\LEETERS-POS-Extender\POS-Sales-Reports\By-Month\"
    CALL :_setVar compareDates "H:\LEETERS-POS-Extender\POS-Sales-Reports\By-Month\Parsed\compareDates.txt"
GOTO :EOF

:_CompareValues
    REM echo %1 %2 %3 %4
    set "ID=%7"
    set "currentDate=%1"
    set "compareDate=%2"
    set /a "AmountDollarPrice=%3"
    set /a "AmountChangePrice=%4"
    set /a "Tax1DollarPrice=%5"
    set /a "Tax1ChangePrice=%6"
    set /a "DiscountDollarPrice=%8"
    set /a "DiscountChangePrice=%9"
GOTO :EOF

:_onScreenDisplay
    REM On Screen Scrolling Output
    CLS & ECHO Processing...
    echo ID, Date, Sales, Taxes, Discount, Total
    echo %1, %currentDate%, $%AmountDollarPrice%.%AmountChangePrice%, $%Tax1DollarPrice%.%Tax1ChangePrice%, $%DiscountDollarPrice%.%DiscountChangePrice%, $%totalDollarPrice%.%totalChangePrice%
GOTO :EOF

:_GenerateOutput
    SET /a totalDollarPrice=%AmountDollarPrice%-%Tax1DollarPrice%-%DiscountDollarPrice%
    SET /a totalChangePrice=%AmountChangePrice%-%Tax1ChangePrice%-%DiscountChangePrice%

    IF %totalChangePrice% GEQ 100 (
        SET /a totalDollarPrice=%totalDollarPrice%+1
        SET /a totalChangePrice=%totalChangePrice%-100
    )

    REM Generates the CSV Output file based on query
    echo ID, Date, Sales, Taxes, Discount, Total >> %scriptPath%\query_output.csv
    echo %1, %currentDate%, $%AmountDollarPrice%.%AmountChangePrice%, $%Tax1DollarPrice%.%Tax1ChangePrice%, $%DiscountDollarPrice%.%DiscountChangePrice%, $%totalDollarPrice%.%totalChangePrice% >> %scriptPath%\query_output.csv
    REM echo %1, %currentDate%, $%dayDollarTotal%.%dayChangeTotal%, $%dayTaxDollarTotal%.%dayTaxChangeTotal%, %DiscountChangePrice%, Re-calculate >> query_output.csv
GOTO :EOF

:_GenerateLogFiles
GOTO :EOF

:_setVar
    set "%1=%2"
GOTO :EOF
```

The script appears to be running fine, just the output it is generating has a running total for the first compared date but lists the last comparedDate in the loop. It's simply not outputting the values for each day correctly. I'm hoping to find someone here who is good at VB Macro's/MS Access that could provide me with logic to get what I need done. If it works it works.

If anyone would like, I could provide the actual files (probably in a Google Docs shared ZIP archive via an added link.

Comment: I suggest using the query designer in AcceSs to aggregate by date. You are looking for a query which contains `GROUP BY`. Its not clear what output you want or how to join the 2 tables: you seem to have a many-to-many situation with multiple records for each date in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea for your question is creating some temporary table with temporary unique key for each table. 
For an instance you can create a key by combining string "KEY" with date.
So the query will be look like this

```
    SELECT "KEY-" & CStr(SlipDate) AS keyTemp, 
        SUM(Cash),SUM(Credit),
        SUM(SC),
        SUM(Off By),
        SUM(Total) INTO TABLE_TEMP_1
    FROM SLIPDATE
    GROUP BY SlipDate 


    SELECT "KEY-" & CStr(Date) AS keyTemp, 
        SUM(Amount),
        SUM(Tax 1),
        SUM(Tax 2),
        SUM(Tax 3),
        SUM(Discount)  INTO TABLE_TEMP_2  
        FROM SALESREPORT
    GROUP BY Date
```

After create two temporary table, you can join these tables using simple SQL and create a new field to validate the field.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, you have helped tremendously. After Doing as you instructed, QUERY1 Appears to be working but QUERY2 Does not seem to add the values for each date range. They list list out by transaction/ID. Please see modified queries below. Also, as a note the DATETIME column contains both the Date and Time of each transaction (I'm not sure if I need to throw the date into a temporary variable and then run the query?

Comment: QUERY1: `SELECT CStr(SlipDate) AS sumByDate, Sum(Cash) AS CashSum, Sum(Credit) AS CreditSum, Sum(SC) AS SCSum, Sum(OFFBY) AS OffbySum, Sum(Cash + Credit + SC + OFFBY) AS Total INTO SLIP_QUERY_TABLE
FROM DEPOSITSLIPS
GROUP BY SlipDate;`

Comment: QUERY2: `SELECT CStr(Left(DATETIME,Len(DATETIME)-11)) AS keyTemp, SUM(Amount), SUM(Tax1), SUM(Tax2), SUM(Tax3), SUM(Discount), SUM(Amount + Tax1 + Tax2 + Tax3 - Discount) AS Total  INTO SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TABLE
FROM SALES
GROUP BY DATETIME;`

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured it out. I did need to create one additional table as a temp though I'm sure there is a cleaner way. Once the date is cleaned up then the method you describe works. I will update my specific solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, what I'm trying to do gave you the concept here.

Answer (score 0):

Per the solution provided, I created three queries and run in order. I will clean this up by making a VB function shortly, but this is basically how it works:

**[SLIP QUERY]**

This table creates the `SLIP_QUERY_TABLE`

```
SELECT CStr(SlipDate) AS sumByDate, Sum(Cash) AS CashSum, Sum(Credit) AS CreditSum, Sum(SC) AS SCSum, Sum(OFFBY) AS OffbySum, Sum(Cash + Credit + SC + OFFBY) AS Total INTO SLIP_QUERY_TABLE
FROM DEPOSITSLIPS
GROUP BY SlipDate;
```

**[SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TMP]**

This Table creates a temporary table `SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TABLE_TMP` in order to be able to cleanup the values for further use.

```
SELECT CStr(Left(DATETIME,Len(DATETIME)-11)) AS keyTemp, SUM(Amount) AS Expr1, SUM(Tax1) AS Expr2, SUM(Tax2) AS Expr3, SUM(Tax3) AS Expr4, SUM(Discount) AS Expr5 INTO SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TABLE_TMP
FROM SALES
GROUP BY DATETIME;
```

**[SALES_REPORT_QUERY_OUTPUT]**

And this Query uses the `SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TABLE_TMP` table to generate the `SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TABLE` output table.

```
SELECT CStr(keyTemp) AS dateRange, Sum(Expr1) AS Amount, Sum(Expr2) AS Tax1, Sum(Expr3) AS Tax2 , Sum(Expr4) AS Tax3, Sum(Expr5) AS Discount, Sum(Expr1+Expr2+Expr3+Expr4-Expr5) AS Total INTO SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TABLE
FROM SALES_REPORT_QUERY_TABLE_TMP
GROUP BY keyTemp;
```

Clearly everything needs some cleanup, maybe even one nice query, but I'm happy to say it's working. I really appreciate the help!!!